# How can I get the raw tx hex from bitcoind with the txid?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, raw-transaction

Is there any way to get the raw tx hex when I know the txid using `bitcoind` not third party. Currently I'm using a thirdparty (blockcypher) but now I want to switch to `bitcoind`.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the transaction index by using setting `txindex=1` in your bitcoin.conf file or starting bitcoind with the `-txindex` option. This option will allow you to use the `getrawtransaction` command on any transaction in the Bitcoin blockchain or in the node's mempool.

Note that setting this option will require you to reindex bitcoind if it was not already enabled.